# How to properly return an empty function?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm using a run-time assignment of functions to account for browser differences.  However for un-supported browsers, I want to return an empty function so that a JavaScript error is not thrown.

But, jslint complains about empty functions.  What is the jslint happy way to do this?

> Empty block.

```
$R.functionNull = function () {
    // events not supported;
};

$R.Constructor.prototype.createEvent = (function () {
    if (doc.createEvent) {
        return function (type) {
            var event = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent(type, true, false);
            $NS.eachKey(this, function (val) {
                val.dispatchEvent(event);
            });
        };
    }
    if (doc.createEventObject) {
        return function (type) {
            var event = doc.createEventObject();
            event.eventType = type;
            $NS.eachKey(this, function (val) {
                val.fireEvent('on' + type, event);
            });
        };
    }
    return $R.functionNull;
}());
```

Comment: [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) has an option to tolerate empty blocks, I do not think jslint has that option.

Comment: Jslint like things to be explicit and easy to read, hence I think it expects you to return undefined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a body to your function and have it return `undefined`:

```
$R.functionNull = function() {
    // Events not supported.
    return undefined;
};
```

This keeps the same semantics as a "truly empty" function, and should satisfy JSLint.

Comment: still it's easier to write `void 0` and it avoids the arguments too :P

Answer (score 15):

Use the lambda expression:

```
$R.functionNull = () => void 0;
```

Answer (score 8):

For me this works best:

```js
emptyFunction = Function();

console.log(emptyFunction); // logs 'ƒ anonymous() {}'
console.log(emptyFunction()); // logs 'undefined'
```

It's so short that I wouldn't even assign it to a variable (of course you can also use a constant-like variable "EF" or so, that's even shorter and doesn't need the additioal "()" brackets). Just use "Function()" anywhere you need a truly empty function, that doesn't even have a name, not even when you assign it to a variable, and that's the small behaviour difference between my solution and Frédéric's:

```js
// --- Frédéric ---

emptyFunction = function() {
   return undefined;
}

console.log(emptyFunction.name); // logs '"emptyFunction"'

// --- me ---

emptyFunction = Function();

console.log(emptyFunction.name); // logs '""' (or '"anonymous"' in chrome, to be fair)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about returning

`return () => undefined;`

instead of

`return $R.functionNull;`

Comment: Just a sidenote for others: () => void 0; as seen in splintor's answer is safer because it always returns undefined and cannot get overriden. I had to learn that the hard way...